# Manually setting basemap using ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, desktop, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api

Looked over the example can NOT figure out how to set basemap MANUALLY. I don't want a dijit widget, or any other libraries or anything like that. Just want to manually set a basemap to any of the already available types like Topographic, Satellites, Streets, etc.

Following this API reference:

[Object: esri/basemaps](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.basemaps-amd.html)

**The part I can't figure out is marked with question marks.** If some could help me out, would really appreciate it.

```
require([
    "esri/basemaps",
    "esri/map",
    "dojo/domReady!"
], function (esriBasemaps, Map) {



/* ------------------------------------- */
/* Basemap add one of the existing maps. */
/* ------------------------------------- */
esriBasemaps.myBasemap = {
    baseMapLayers ???
};



var map = new Map("map", {
    basemap: "myBasemap",
    center: [-118, 34.5],
    zoom: 8
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the [esri/basemaps documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/esri.basemaps-amd.html) works fine, combined with the [create a map sample](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/map_simple.html).

Here's the part you wondered about:

```
esriBasemaps.myBasemap = {
  baseMapLayers: [
    {
      url: "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/DeLorme_World_Base_Map/MapServer"
    }
  ],
  title: "My Basemap"
};
```

Here's a full example. Copy and paste the following into the [ArcGIS API for JavaScript Sandbox](http://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/sandbox/sandbox.html) to see how it works.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      body {
        background-color: #FFF;
        overflow: hidden;
        font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/"></script>
    <script>
      var map;

      require(["esri/basemaps", "esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(esriBasemaps, Map) {
        esriBasemaps.myBasemap = {
          baseMapLayers: [
            {
              url: "http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Specialty/DeLorme_World_Base_Map/MapServer"
            }
          ],
          title: "My Basemap"
        };
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "myBasemap",
          center: [-122.45, 37.75], // longitude, latitude
          zoom: 13
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```